# How can I make an entries query based on currentUser is author or relatedTo currentUser

Tags: templating, relatedto, current-user, author

My project requires a notifications area. I want to list all notification entries that were created by currentUser or sent to currentUser.

I can do created by = `craft.entries().section('thename').authorId(currentUser.id).all()`

I can do sent to = `craft.entries().section('thename').relatedTo({ targetElement: currentUser, field: 'thefield' }).all()`

But is there a single query that will get both?

Answer (score 1):

A blanket `relatedTo` query should do the trick.

```
craft.entries().section('thename').relatedTo(currentUser).all()
```

Comment: First thing I tried and no. I found https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2392#issuecomment-363185158 where Brandon Kelly says author isn't stored the same as other fields.